# Appcelerator Studio No Internet Development

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Is there a way to Code in Appcelerator without Internet? I am traveling soon and would like to code when I am on the flight etc.

Any idea?
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can work in offline mode with Appcelerator studio but with some restrictions.

Before you go offline you need to do the following

1. Login into studio at least once
2. Maintain valid session - In general, session valid for 3 days (I
   think so!)
3. Need to run your project at least once - otherwise, you will get
   `You are offline but this is the first time you are building this
   application with this configuration. You must be online once with
   this build configuration and then you can do subsequent builds
   offline`